# Is there any real point in having exercise variety?

Tags: exercise

My work out involves rotating between the following six exercises, usually doing a combination of two at a time:

1. Deadlift
2. High bar back Squat
3. Overhead press
4. Bench
5. Pendlay row

Many workout programs I see suggest doing "accesory work" i.e: additional assistance exercises to get my numbers up. My question is this actually effective? Does having a variety of exercises actually have benefits in hypertrophy/gains/..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good Drs. Baraki and Feigenbaum discuss this question in great depth on [Episode 164 of the Barbell Medicine Podcast](https://m.soundcloud.com/user-344313169/episode-164-exercise-variation), listen to that for the long version of this answer.

The short version is that research has highlighted at least three substantial benefits of exercise variation:

- mitigation of injury risk associated with overuse/overtraining [(1)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21259156/), [(2)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28288281/), [(3)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30135085/)
- improved motor learning/neurological adaptation [(4)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6091866/)
- better strength outcomes when compared to changing load only [(5)](https://journals.lww.com/nsca-jscr/fulltext/2014/11000/changes_in_exercises_are_more_effective_than_in.9.aspx)

So to directly answer the question: exercise variation is generally a great idea. As you get stronger, you’ll likely find the squat in particular to be a pretty fatiguing movement. In my own training, I cannot squat every workout because I’ll get into overtraining very quickly. Instead, I squat once a week, and on the other two days, I’m doing a lower fatigue squat variation like a leg press or Bulgarian split squat.