# Why do exercises which produce less fatigue at higher levels?

Tags: squats, gym

In reference to [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/46918/38114), I want to ask why would we want to do low fatigue exercises at advanced levels? How I think about it right now is, fatigue and how exhausted the muscles are, is propotional, hence more fatigue would be better for both hypertrophy/ strength gains.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing metabolic stress with fatigue.

Metabolic stress comes from performing a set while the muscle becomes continuously weaker until it reaches the point that it can no longer perform the set.

Fatigue is just exhaustion or lack of energy. It can be both mental and physical. I could run 40km and a moderate pace and it would fatigue me. It wouldn't produce the signaling necessary to produce hypertrophy, so my legs wouldn't grow.

Metabolic stress will cause fatigue, but fatigue does not necessarily come from metabolic stress.

In the case of the answer, he was referring to squats. When you're squatting in to 150kg+ range, it can be *exhausting*. Not just in your legs, but your whole body can get its energy just sucked right out. Because of that, you may not even get enough stimulus in the legs to induce hypertrophy because some other part of your body wasn't able to last long enough to complete the lift. You may be too mentally or physically fatigued to do anything else.

So a lot of advanced people will instead swap to a more targeted exercise that's less fatiguing like machine hack squats or leg press. These allow you to push far more intensely in the legs without exhausting out the rest of the body.

Comment: Yep, good summary of the idea I was getting at with that answer.